# Trying to display images using UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

I want to create an simple app that will contain one centered image at the first start screen, than upon swipe gesture(right, left) change images.

I'm very new to this so here is what I though is what I'm looking for http://idevzilla.com/2010/09/16/uiscrollview-a-really-simple-tutorial/ .

This is the code I have in my controller implementation :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSMutableDictionary *myDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

        [myDictionary setObject:@"img1.jpg" forKey:@"http://www.testweb.com"];
        [myDictionary setObject:@"img2.jpg" forKey:@"http://www.test2.com"];

        UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
        scroll.pagingEnabled = YES;
        NSInteger numberOfViews = [myDictionary count];

        for (NSString* key in myDictionary) {

                UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:[myDictionary objectForKey:key]]];
                CGRect rect = CGRectMake(10.0f, 90.0f, image.size.width, image.size.height);

                UIImageView * imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];

                [imageView setImage:image];

                CGPoint superCenter = CGPointMake([self.view bounds].size.width / 2.0, [self.view bounds].size.height / 2.0);

                [imageView setCenter:superCenter];
                self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

                [scroll addSubview:imageView];


        }
        scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * numberOfViews, self.view.frame.size.height);


        [self.view addSubview:scroll];

}
```

My first issue here is that I get `img2` on my initial screen instead of `img1`. And second issue is when I swipe right I get white screen and no image on it. Any suggestions what I missed, what I can try/read etc?

**EDIT :**

I'm looking to do this the "lightest" possible way, using no fancy galleries api etc. Just display couple of really small images(i.e 200x200 px) centered on the screen that I can swipe back and forth(should't be too hard). Well everything is hard when learning a new language.

Comment: Refer the following link:Scrolling Example
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Scrolling/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a project on github [MWPhotoBrowser](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser) that allows you to put in a set of images which are viewed one at a time. You can then scroll from one image to the next with a swipe gesture. It is also easy to add functionality and it should give you a good understanding of how this is done. There is also Apple's [PhotoScroller example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html) which gives you straight forward code in how to do this same thing and also tile your images. Since you are new to iOS you may want to first look at both of these examples or possibly just use them as your photo viewer.

Comment: thanks for your response, I've looked trough both examples and they seem to be very good and complex implementation of actual image galleries. I don't really intend to create image gallery but really simple image at each page when clicked will do something. I just want to learn this from ground up

Comment: I made a new project with exactly the same code as you have and compiled it in an iPod iOS 5 Simulator. I got the two images on top of each other. This is because you are cycling through each key and adding each image to the same position in the scroll. To fix this add:

        int i = 0; //above the for loop
Then change this to:
CGPoint superCenter = CGPointMake(([self.view bounds].size.width / 2.0) + i * [self.view bounds].size.width, [self.view bounds].size.height / 2.0);

and add i++; below this statement

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is likely to be the fact that you are setting `CGRect rect = CGRectMake(10.0f, 90.0f, image.size.width, image.size.height);` for both of your image views. This means that *both* of your `UIImageView` objects are placed in exactly the same position (both are positioned at 10.f on the x-coordinate of the scrollview). As the second image view is added last it covers the first and means that there is white space to the right of it.

In order to fix this you could try something like...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    //your setup code

    float xPosition = 10.f;
    for (NSString* key in myDictionary) {
        UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:[myDictionary objectForKey:key]]];
        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(xPosition, 90.0f, image.size.width, image.size.height);
        xPosition += image.size.width;
        //rest of your code...
    }
    //rest of your code
}
```

The above would mean that the second view is positioned on the x-coordinate at 10 + the width of the first image. Note that I haven't tested my answer.

Comment: thank your for your response, that didn't seem to fix anything

Answer (score 0):

First off the images are placed on top of each other.

```
CGPoint superCenter = CGPointMake([self.view bounds].size.width / 2.0, [self.view bounds].size.height / 2.0);
[imageView setCenter:superCenter];
```

Right here you are setting both images to be placed at the center of the screen. The second thing is your using an NSDictionary and looping through the keys. NSDictionary are not orders like an array is. You would have to sort the keys to us it in a specific order. So Barjavel had it right but skipped over the fact your setting the images to center. Try this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSArray *myArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"img1.jpg", @:image2.jpg", nil];
    UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    scroll.pagingEnabled = YES;
    NSInteger numberOfViews = [myArray count];
    int xPosition = 0;
    for (NSString* image in myArray) {
        UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:image];
        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(xPosition, 90.0f, image.size.width, image.size.height);

        UIImageView * imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
        [imageView setImage:image];
        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [scroll addSubview:imageView];
        xPosition += image.size.width;
    }
    scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * numberOfViews, self.view.frame.size.height);

    [self.view addSubview:scroll];

}
```

Comment: now I just realized I actually meant to implement page control , sorry now I see both pictures and realize what this does